# mobx autorun not firing

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I have code like this:

```js
export const queryData = observable({
    groupBy: "node"
});

autorun(()=> {
    console.log(queryData.groupBy);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(queryData));
});
```

And i have react components where i do :

```js
@observer
class MyPage extends React.Component<IProps, {}>
{

    handleSelect(value: string)
    {
        queryData.groupBy = value;
    }
}
```

Other components that use `queryData.groupBy` show the updated value. Even the devtools shows the value being updated in the console log.

However, the `autorun()` is not fired on the property change. (its fired only once at the begining of the program)

Answer (score 0):

ok apparently it was firing, just that enabling mobx-devtools made the output print in sub-hierarchy of some dev-tool related output